# Train a reinforcement learning model with a large amount of images

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning

I am tentatively trying to train a deep reinforcement learning model the maze escaping task, and each time it takes one image as the input (e.g., a different "maze").

Suppose I have about 10K different maze images, and the ideal case is that after training N mazes, my model would do a good job to quickly solve the puzzle in the rest 10K - N images.

I am writing to inquire some good idea/empirical evidences on how to select a good N for the training task.

And in general, how should I estimate and enhance the ability of "transfer learning" of my reinforcement model? Make it more generalized?

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is not clear to me. What else do you give to your model apart from the image of the maze to help it to solve the escaping task?

Comment: @Neb  Just a very standard `env`. Something like https://github.com/samyzaf/tdfmaze/blob/master/tdfmaze.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Firstly,***

I strongly recommend you to use **2D arrays** for the maps of the mazes instead of **images**, it would do your model a huge favor, becuse **it's a more feature extracted approach**. try using 2D arrays in which walls are demonstrated by ones upon the ground of zeros.

***And about finding the optimized N:***

Your **model architecture is way more important than the share of training data** in all of the data or the **batch sizes**. It's better to make a well designed model and then to find the optimized amount of N by testing different Ns(becuse it is only one variable, the process of optimizing N can be easily done by you yourself).